# Explicit Comparator<T> and Violation of Consistency with the Equals method in Collections

Tags: java, collections

It is recommended that when using user-defined classes in collections, when we implement a `Comparable<T>` interface, the `compareTo(T arg)` method of the interface should be consistent with the `equals(Object obj)` method. That means if the compareTo method is returning '0' when comparing two objects, then their equals method should return 'true'.

But what if we pass an explicit `Comparator<T>` to the collection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The docs of [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) recommend, but do not require, the same:

> Caution should be exercised when using a comparator capable of imposing an ordering inconsistent with equals to order a sorted set (or sorted map). Suppose a sorted set (or sorted map) with an explicit comparator c is used with elements (or keys) drawn from a set S. If the ordering imposed by c on S is inconsistent with equals, the sorted set (or sorted map) will behave "strangely." In particular the sorted set (or sorted map) will violate the general contract for set (or map), which is defined in terms of equals.

Comment: …and a comparator as simple as [`String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER) does already have the property of returning zero for some strings whose `equals` will return `false`.